The Capacitor ML Kit Barcode Scanning Plugin version 6.0.0 does not work on iOS
I am using Vue 3.x and Ionic 7, and running the Capacitor ML Kit Barcode Scanning Plugin on a physical iOS 17 device.
In version 6.0.0 of the plugin, invoking any BarcodeScanner method on iOS results in the Xcode log always displaying the error: {“code”:“UNIMPLEMENTED”}.
Have any suggestions?

Hi @RGe,
Thanks for your suggestions. I've checked everything as advised, but the issue persists. Additionally, I'm encountering two Xcode warnings that might be affecting the plugin:
'[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' runs during every build because it doesn't specify any outputs. Could this be affecting plugin integration?
No platform load command found in 'MLKitBarcodeScanning.framework'. Could this indicate a loading issue?
Any further advice would be appreciated!

I discovered that the issue was due to the version of @capacitor/cli needing to be updated to 6.0.0. After updating to this version, everything worked normally.

Please take a look at the official iOS Troubleshooting Guide:

On iOS, this can happen if Capacitor doesn't find the plugins or can't inject its code into the WebView.
First of all, make sure the plugin is installed and appears in the package.json.
Then, run npx cap sync ios.
Finally, check that the plugin is in ios/App/Podfile. If the plugin is not listed, make sure your Podfile looks like this one and run npx cap sync again.
If still getting the "Plugin not implemented" error, make sure you don't have WKAppBoundDomains key in ios/App/App/Info.plist, that prevents Capacitor's and Plugins code from injecting. Remove the key if not needed, or if it can't be removed, add limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains to your capacitor config file with true value inside the ios object.

